# How to make Ruby's sleep method delay printing on a Rails web page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a Ruby script that inserts a slight delay as it prints characters on the console. I would like to do the same thing on a Web page, but when I call the script from a demo site, everything prints out at once. Here's the script:

```
def add_breath(text, pause)
    # print pause
    char_list = text.scan(/./)
    print "\n"
    # now iterate through the char list and print each char with a slight delay
    for char in char_list
        if char == " "   #or char == "?" or char == "!" or punctuation 
            sleep(0.02)
            print char
        elsif char == "," or char == "." or char == "!" or char == ":"
            sleep(0.22)
            print char
        elsif char == '@'
            sleep(pause)
        elsif char == char.downcase or char == char.upcase
            sleep(0.05)
            print char
        end
    end
    sleep(0.5)
    print "\n"
    #writes user input to file
    target = File.open("sleep.txt", 'w') 
    target.write(text)
    target.write("\n") 
    target.close()
end


text =  "Make your sentences breath like this -- @O@M@G@!@ -- with the 'at' character (on US keyboards, that's shift+2). Your turn:"
# text = "Well, give it a try:"
add_breath(text, 0.3) 

text = gets
puts "OK, now tell me how long each breath should be (try 0.3):"
pause = gets.to_f
add_breath(text, pause)
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby on rails renders the HTML that is sent to the browser from the server. So the sleep method you are using will only delay the server to complete rendering the page.

If you want this in the browser, you will have to use javascript.

Comment: . . . or set up a streaming service for the text, but that seems overkill for OP's needs (and may well still be best with JS receiving the text anyhow)

Comment: @nathanvda absolutely r8. to execute it you need to manage from js. or to check the controller action you need to call the action through curl command from the console

Comment: Thanks, folks, I'll try JS.